# My XAMPP localhost is not running what can I do?

Tags: php, apache, web-services, xampp, localhost

Recently, I installed `xampp 5.6.3` successfully.  For this, I turned my UAC off and uninstalled my antivirus, but now it's not working. From control panel, I started Apache, MySQL and filezilla. For my Skype I changed the port of Apache from 443 to 4433. And now it's running.But whenever I got to browser and go to `http://localhost` it shows a blank page with nothing.So please help me.It is hampering in learning PHP. I will be really thankful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed the Apache port from 443 to 4433, then you need to change your URL accordingly:

```
http://localhost:4433
```

Note: you can use netstat from a command prompt to see if the port is running.

```
netstat -a | find "4433"
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490947.aspx